# How to create an XML attribute that represents an object

Tags: java, xml

I'm writing integration tests for a project I'm working on and I'm stuck. I have an object (let's call it travelerDetail) that stores a list of objects that represent seats booked on a flight and I want to create a travelDetail element in xml that has an attribute that reflects these seats. Right now it's sort of like:

```
<SEAT DDATE="2012-05-22" TCHG="07:30:10" ROW="11" LETTER="A" POSN="R" SIDE="L" EXIT="N"   ID="D164771" CKIN="" ONBORD="" CHGCDE="C" PAGE="1" DCHG="2012-05-22 12:20:44.396" TCHG="16:43:45"  PCHG="07272" />

<TRAVELERDETAIL ITN="3224"  PDDATE="07:30:10" DOW="4" ORIG="BLI" DEST="LAS" FINALDST="LAS" PTYPE="R" LNAME="SPADE" FNAME="ADULTONE"  SFEE1="0.00" SFEE2="0.00" SFEE3="0.00" NOREFUND="" FARE="127.44" COST="0.00" FTAX="9.56" PFC="4.50" FSC="0.00" FEDEX="3.80" SECCHG="2.50" DISCAMT="0.00" ALLOCFARE="127.44" MILES="954" FUELGAL="0.000" FUELRATE="0.000" FUELPRICE="0.00" CNTRY="USA" BOOKTIME="2012-05-22 12:20:44.396" BKCHG="0.00" WAITING="N" TFLT="" BAGS="0" PPBAGS="1" PPFEE="19.99" APBAGS="0" APFEE="0.00" TPFEE="0.00" FREEBAGS="0" DEPART="2012-05-22 12:20:44.396" ARRIVE="2012-05-22 12:20:44.396" GENDER="M" DOB="1970-01-01" DHSSEQ="0" CHGCDE="A" PAGE="0" DCHG="2012-05-22" TCHG="07:30:10" REC_ID="-10"/>
```

The TravelerDetail class maintains a list of Seats that the traveler might have booked on the flight. Can I create xml test data like this?

Comment: What is your question? You *can* create XML like this. But I doubt you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO XML attribute can be a property of any object...not an object by itself

This is probably how you want your xml to look like.

```
<TRAVELERDETAIL ITN="3224"  PDDATE="07:30:10" DOW="4" ORIG="BLI" DEST="LAS" FINALDST="LAS" PTYPE="R" LNAME="SPADE" FNAME="ADULTONE"  SFEE1="0.00" SFEE2="0.00" SFEE3="0.00" NOREFUND="" FARE="127.44" COST="0.00" FTAX="9.56" PFC="4.50" FSC="0.00" FEDEX="3.80" SECCHG="2.50" DISCAMT="0.00" ALLOCFARE="127.44" MILES="954" FUELGAL="0.000" FUELRATE="0.000" FUELPRICE="0.00" CNTRY="USA" BOOKTIME="2012-05-22 12:20:44.396" BKCHG="0.00" WAITING="N" TFLT="" BAGS="0" PPBAGS="1" PPFEE="19.99" APBAGS="0" APFEE="0.00" TPFEE="0.00" FREEBAGS="0" DEPART="2012-05-22 12:20:44.396" ARRIVE="2012-05-22 12:20:44.396" GENDER="M" DOB="1970-01-01" DHSSEQ="0" CHGCDE="A" PAGE="0" DCHG="2012-05-22" TCHG="07:30:10" REC_ID="-10">
   <SEAT DDATE="2012-05-22" TCHG="07:30:10" ROW="11" LETTER="A" POSN="R" SIDE="L" EXIT="N"   ID="D164771" CKIN="" ONBORD="" CHGCDE="C" PAGE="1" DCHG="2012-05-22 12:20:44.396" TCHG="16:43:45"  PCHG="07272"/>
   <SEAT /> ...

</TRAVELERDETAIL>
```

Of course you can have any number of seats assigned to your TRAVELERDETAIL as it is identified by Itinerary

Answer (score 0):

You can nest XML elements.

```
<TRAVELERDETAIL>
    <SEAT />
    <SEAT />
</TRAVELERDETAIL>
```